# Present Progressive Tense

Tags: phrase-meaning

Would you please clarify, if I can use 
'I am not driving the car' 
 instead of 
'I am not going to drive the car'?

Comment: They're different in meaning, though in some contexts they can have similar implications. Please provide context for the respective usage.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What about this: it's snowing, the road is wet and fluffy, I am too worn-out to drive any more, I am pulling up...

Comment: Again, either could be used. I've been trying to think of some good examples of each usage, and I honestly haven't really come up with any that clearly distinguish between the two.

Comment: going to is used as a future.

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine you're driving around the States with your friend Joe, and you take turns at the wheel and drive every other day. Tomorrow it's Joe's turn and your day off - "I'm not driving the car tomorrow" (Joe is) - this is your *arrangement* with Joe.

Let's now imagione that you usually drive to work but you have a sore ankle - "I'm not going to drive the car tomorrow" (I'm going to rest my ankle). It's my *intention* not to drive so that I can rest my ankle.

Answer (score 0):

You can say "I am not driving the car", but it is a little ambiguous, as it can also mean you are not doing it in the present, rather than you will not in the future. This is normally clear from context, however.